# asp mvc noob: why is my mvc app not filling from it's seed data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am following the ASP MVC 3 music store tutorial--translating the C# into VB. 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

I have a class called SampleData that is supposed to hold the data for the application. It looks like this:

```
 Public Class SampleData
        Inherits DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of MusicStoreEntities)

        Protected Overrides Sub Seed(context As MusicStoreEntities)
            Dim genres As Genre() = { _
                New Genre() With {.name = "Rock"},
                New Genre() With {.name = "Jazz"},
               ... more genres...
             }
```

I have a class called MusicStoreEntities that inherits from DbContext like this:

```
Public Class MusicStoreEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Property albums As DbSet(Of Album)
    Property genres As DbSet(Of Genre)
```

My controller is supposed to return a view that lists the genres but the list of genres is empty.

```
    ' GET: /Store
    Dim storeDB As MusicStoreEntities = New MusicStoreEntities()

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim genres As List(Of Genre) = storeDB.genres.ToList
        Return View(genres)
    End Function
```

I am also calling my seed in Application_start, located in global.asax

```
Sub Application_Start()
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
           New MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData())
```

Basically, I should see all of the genres but don't.

[image]

I have no idea how to go about debugging. Where do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling your seed in your Application_start, located in global.asax?

I don't know vb but here's the c#:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    Database.SetInitializer(new SampleData());
}
```

Altering `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` could also help, it will force your database to drop and reseed every time the program is run.

Comment: Have you changed your model to force the drop?  What happens if you change it to from DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges to DropCreateDatabaseAlways, so it will always drop it and reseed, just to be sure your seed function is being called.

Comment: that was it. if you change your answer to reflect your comment i will accept.

Comment: Thank you @MarkOreta! It worked! Changed DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges to DropCreateDataBaseAlways and now it works perfectly!